# Extract IP addresses in each line of file in shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have this input file in ubuntu:

```
146.14.142.96.17747 197.102.40.184.13748:
146.14.142.96.17747 197.102.40.184.13749: 
146.14.142.96.17747 197.102.40.184.13750:
146.114.142.96.17747 197.102.40.184.13751:
46.14.142.96.17747 197.102.40.184.13752:
```

and I'd like to have the output like this using shell scripting:

separate two IPs without ports number
I mean delete ports

```
146.14.142.96 197.102.40.184
146.14.142.96 197.102.40.184 
146.14.142.96 197.102.40.184
146.114.142.96 197.102.40.184
46.14.142.96 197.102.40.184
```

Comment: In linux, use ["sed"](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) tool with a grep.

Comment: @Diogo tnx. i'm not expert in regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lines formatted exactly as shown in the question, this will do:

```
sed -E 's/\.[0-9]+[ :]/ /g' input-file
```

How it works:

- The `-E` switch enables [Extended Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions).
- `s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g` globally (`/g`) replaces (`s/`) *SEARCH* with *REPLACE*.
- `\.[0-9]+[ :]` matches a dot following any positive number of digits following a space or a colon.

However, this will break if the formatting varies even slightly. This approach may result robuster:

```
sed -E 's/(([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+)[^ ]+/\1/g' input-file
```

How it works:

- `([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+` matches an IP (three digit groups followed by dots plus an additional digit group).
- The surrounding parentheses declare the previous match as the first submatch (`\1`).
- `[^ ]+` matches any non-space character that follows the IP.

Comment: this is not working in sum ips it cuts the ip.

Comment: 181.173.82.61 250.66.33.195 
181.173.82.60 250.66.33.195 
181.173.82 229.96.193 
181.173.83 245.228.178 
181.173.82.61 250.66.33.195 
181.173.82.60 250.66.33.195 
172.30.79 247.236.141

Comment: 172.30.79 247.236.141  this is not valid ip

Comment: Look up the line containing the IP starting with `172.30.79`. I assume it had a different format.

Comment: i min plz im checking it now

Comment: yeap you right! apologies :)

Comment: I've added a second approach that should depend a little less on the formatting (works as long as there's a space before the second IP).

Comment: could you plz tell me what is / /g is doing? replacing with what?

Comment: `/ /` replaces the first match with a space. `/ /g` replaces all matches with a space.

Comment: and 1 more question: how can i using grep to find lines that have these HTTP/1.0 200 OK and HTTP/1.1 OK and ...

Comment: Is it intentional that *HTTP/1.1 OK* doesn't contain the status code? If it isn't `grep 'HTTP/1.[01] 200 OK'` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search and replace using regex

```
(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+(:?)
```

and replace text

```
\1
```

Various tools support regex search and replace though the dialect can be slightly different. The above works with Notepad++.

Or in vim you can do

```
:s/\(\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+\)\.\d\+\(:\?\)/\1/g
```

Comment: this is not working grep '(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\d+(:?)'

Comment: for 1 ip i use this cut -d "." -f -4 and its working

Comment: but for 2 IPs i dont know what to do :(